# Simulating Bluetooth Headset profile on Windows C#

Tags: c#, android, .net, bluetooth

I am trying to build a console application that can emulate the Bluetooth Headset profile. The idea is that an Android phone will connect to the application and send audio(even the call audio) to the console application.

On the top level of the Bluetooth stack resides the services and profiles, each service and profile is identified by a unique UUID. Some UUIDs are reserved for standard Bluetooth services as described here: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/

What I understand is that the console application needs to: 1st advertise the Headset service and 2nd following the headset profile specifications given here: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/headset-profile-1-2/ handle incoming and outgoing messages accordingly.

Here is the code I have written for advertising the headset service:

```
static async Task StartServer() 
    {
        try
        {
            var headsetServiceId = RfcommServiceId.FromShortId(0x1108);
            rfcommProvider = await RfcommServiceProvider.CreateAsync(headsetServiceId);
            if (rfcommProvider == null) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Couldn't create service provider for the specified UUID");
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("looks like bluetooth is disabled, exception={0} ",ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
        socketListener = new StreamSocketListener();
        StreamSocketListenerControl socketControl = socketListener.Control;
        socketControl.QualityOfService = SocketQualityOfService.LowLatency;
        socketListener.ConnectionReceived += (listener, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ConnectionRequestReceived called");
            ResetSocketListener();
            try
            {
                rfcommProvider.StopAdvertising();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"caught exception=[{ex.Message}] when stopping advertisitng]");
            }
            //TODO: Handle connection.
        };
        await socketListener.BindServiceNameAsync(rfcommProvider.ServiceId.AsString(), SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket);
        lock (RfcommServiceLock)
        {
            try
            {
                rfcommProvider.StartAdvertising(socketListener, true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"bluetooth advertising failed, exception={e.Message} ");
                ResetSocketListener();
                throw e;
            }
        }
        Console.Write($"connection is in listening mode, waiting for connection request...");
    }
```

0x1108 is the short UUID representation of the headset profile. The problem here is that the  line:
rfcommProvider = await RfcommServiceProvider.CreateAsync(headsetServiceId);

returns null for '0x1108'. It returns a valid instance for serial port profile '0x1101' and obex file transfer profile '0x1106'.

How can I advertise the headset profile from the console application?

Comment: You can not do it on Windows platform. It is not possible to control SCO connection. All you can do is just create RFCOMM control channel. Also, in classic Bluetooth there is NO short UUID. Classic Bluetooth always uses long UUID.